# Connecting and changing .txt-values to/from a mainfunction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class with private attributes (the attributevalues are imported from a .txt-file) the user should be able to change the values of the attribute. The list looks like this:

```
Rats
Berta/2/4/3/0
Oscar/5/0/3/2
John/-1/-6/-5/-9
```

My question is; where does my messy code go wrong? What am I missing? I've been searching the web for answers for a few days now.

```
#The class
class Rat(object):
    """Defines my class"""
    def __init__(self, rat_name, sleep, joy, full, happiness):
        self.__rat_name = rat_name
        self.__sleep = sleep
        self.__joy = joy
        self.__full = full
        self.__happiness = happiness


    def setfull(self, value, absolute = False):
        """Gives the full attribute a value"""
        try:
            value = int(value)
            if absolute:
                self.__full = value
            else:
                self.__full += value
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def getfull(self):
        """Gives a fullvalue"""
        return self.__full

    def setfull(self, x):
        x = int(x)
        """acess to the full attribute"""
        self.__full = x

    def sethappiness(self, value, absolute = False):
        """Gives the happiness attribute a value"""
        try:
            value = int(value)
            if absolute:
                self.__happiness = value
            else:
                self.__happiness += value
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def gethappiness(self):
        """Gives happiness value"""
        return self.__happiness

    def sethappiness(self, x):
        """access to the happiness attribute"""
        x = int(x)
        self.__happiness = x

    def setsleep(self, value, absolute = False):
        """Gives the sleep attribute a value"""
        try:
            value = int(value)
            if absolute:
                self.__sleep = value
            else:
                self.__sleep += value
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def getsleep(self):
        """Gives a sleep value"""
        return self.__sleep

    def setsleep(self, x):
        """access to the sleep attribute"""
        x = int(x)
        self.__sleep = x

    def setjoy(self, value, absolute = False):
        """Gives a value to the joy attribute"""
        try:
            value = int(value)
            if absolute:
                self.__joy = value
            else:
                self.__joy += value
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def getjoy(self):
        """Gives a joy value"""
        return self.__joy

    def setjoy(self, x):
        """access to the joy attribute"""
        x = int(x)
        self.__joy = x


# main menu functions
    def cheese(self):
        """Feeds the pet"""
        print("- Mmmm cheese!")
        self.__full += 3
        self.__sleep += 1
        self.__joy += 1
        return self.__full, self.__sleep, self.__joy

    def play(self):
        """Plays with the rat"""
        print("- Oh, I'm having fun!")
        self.__full -= 2
        self.__sleep += 2
        self.__joy += 4
        self.__happiness += 2
        return self.__full, self.__sleep, self.__joy, self.__happiness


    def tosleep(self):
        """Let the rat sleep"""
        print("Zzzzzzz")
        self.__sleep -= 7
        self.__joy += 1
        return self.__sleep, self.__joy

    def trap(self):
        """A mousetrap"""
        if self.__full > 5:
            print("The rat is to full to be fooled by a simple mousetrap")
        else:
            print("The rat escaped with a broken tail!")
            self.__joy -= 2
            self.__happiness -=2

        return self.__full, self.__sleep, self.__joy, self.__happiness




    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string that describes the mood of the rat"""
        mood =self.rat_name + " är: "
        if self.__joy > 5:
            mood += "Glad, "
        else:
            mood += "Pissed, "
        if self.__full > 8:
            mood += "overfed, "
        elif self.__full > 0:
            mood += "full, "
        elif self.__full < -5:
            mood += "starving, "
        else:
            mood += "craving cheese and "
        if self.__sleep > 7:
            mood += "very tired and "
        elif self.__sleep > 0:
            mood += "sleepy and "
        else:
            mood += "well rested and "
        if self.__happiness > 7:
            mood += "SUPER HAPPY!"
        elif self.__happiness > 0:
            mood += "quite happy!"
        else:
            mood += "unhappy..."
        return mood


# The list
def listan():
    """Opens and sorts the list"""
    infil = open("ratlist.txt", "r")
    infil.readline
    rats = []

    for row in infil:

        lista = row.split("/")
        print(lista)
        ratname = lista[0]
        ratsleep = int(lista[1])
        ratjoy = int(lista[2])
        ratfull = int(lista[3])
        rathappiness = int(lista[4].strip())
        t = Rat(ratname, ratsleep, ratjoy, ratfull, rathappiness)
        rats.append(t)
    print("Finished")    
    return rats



# the main menu     
def main():
    """The menu"""
    ratzinger = listan()
    choice = None
    while choice != "1":
        print \
        ("""
        The ratkeeper

        1 - Buy a cat
        2 - Listen to your rat
        3 - Let the rat sleep
        4 - Give the rat cheese
        5 - Prepare a mousetrap
        6 - Play with the rat
        7 - Change the values of your rat
        8 - Know the name of my rat
        """)

        choice = input("I want to: ")

        if val == "1":
            print(rat_name, "was tortured and eaten, bye.")
        elif val == "2":
            print(ratzinger)

        elif val == "3":
            ratzinger.tosleep()

        elif val == "4":
            ratzinger.cheese()

        elif val == "5":
            ratzinger.trap()

        elif val == "6":
            ratzinger.play()

        elif val == "7":
            print()

        elif val == "8":
            print()

        else:
            print("Choose a number between one and eight!")

main()

input()
```

Comment: This reads like a transliteration from some other language into Python syntax (which is how many of us start out, so don't worry about it.)  In order to get your code actually running, you can change the line `infil.readline` to `infil.readline()`, so that the method will actually be called to skip the first line of the data file, and then you should decide whether you want to call the input variable `choice` or `val`.  That should get you into the loop, and then you can start rewriting this in Python.

Comment: (Oh, almost forgot: when I made the edit to fix the formatting I changed "Class" to "class" because it would have given a SyntaxError otherwise. I'm assuming that capital C was introduced during the posting process.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above: double underscores in Python do not imply that the marked attribute is private. Double underscores apply name mangling and are used to avoid naming-collisions. If you mean "private" then you should use a single underscore.